# can't center my element which has fixed height in div in another wrapper div which has fixed height also

Tags: html, css, web

I know that centering a element in wrapper, if the element is block level element and the wrapper must have a fixed height div which contains the element must have a fixed height. But i have a button in a wrapper div which in another wrapper div. But cannot center it with `{margin auto, 0px;}.`

My Style

```
        .plusBtn
{
width: 35px;
height: 28px;
display: block;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}

.food {
display: block;

height: 100px;


}
```

My html

```
 <div class="col-md-9 restlist" >
<div class="foodItem">
<div class="food">
<div class="plusBtn">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[My Screenshot about the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xcto.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy if you do know the width and height of your button (which is the case here): Position it 50% from the top and left, then move it back up and left by half of its height and width in pixels.:

```
.food {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
}
.plusBtn {
  width: 35px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-left: -17.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMWNoR

(it might be safer to make the button width 36 px and margin-left -18px to avoid half pixel values.)

Comment: I know that relative positioning is solving the problem but then the responsivity breaks then..

Comment: The button does stand in the parent element. It owerflow abit from left when set left value to 0%. see the ss https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/t31.0-0/p640x640/12371055_1091816694184194_5213628577665938224_o.jpg

Comment: so you want it at the left border of the parent element, not at the horizontal center?

Comment: oh no. I solved the problem by deleting the left margin value of plusbtn. Thanks for your reply :) Your solution  worked as a charm. :)

Comment: if you want it at the left border like in your picture, you also have to consider the thickness of the border. Have a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyEYMe

Answer (score 0):

Your display should be inline-block, then you can center it by adding the text-center class to the div wrapping the button (its parent) this is the .plusBtn class. And finally, modify the class for the vertical center which the most fuid way to do it is by not instantiating a height, instead use padding to get the height desired off the child within it.

This is what you need:

```
 .food{
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid red;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:27px 0 35px;
 }

 .plusBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Here is your code in a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxLPLx)